# Prove that if $g(x)$ is uniformly continuous in $(a,b]$ and $[b,c)$ then is uniformly continuous in $(a,c)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I open this question to check my own proof and to ask a related question.

My proof: if $g(x)$ is uniformly continuous in $(a,b]$ and $[b,c)$ then

> $$\forall\varepsilon_1>0,\exists\delta_1>0,\forall x\in (a,b]:|x-b|<\delta_1\implies|g(x)-g(b)|<\varepsilon_1$$
>   $$\forall\varepsilon_2>0,\exists\delta_2>0,\forall y\in [b,c):|y-b|<\delta_2\implies|g(y)-g(b)|<\varepsilon_2$$

If we call $\varepsilon_0=\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_2$ and $\delta_0=\delta_1+\delta_2$ and due triangle inequality

> $$|x-y|\le|x-b|+|y-b|\\|g(x)-g(y)|\le|g(x)-g(b)|+|g(y)-g(b)|$$

Then we have the case that

> $$\forall\varepsilon_0>0,\exists\delta_0>0,\forall x\in (a,b]\land\forall y\in [b,c):|x-y|<\delta_0\implies|g(x)-g(y)|<\varepsilon_0\tag{1}$$

And by definition of $g(x)$ we have too that

> $$\forall\varepsilon_0>0,\exists\delta_a>0,\forall x,y\in (a,b]:|x-y|<\delta_a\implies|g(x)-g(y)|<\varepsilon_0\tag{2}$$
>   $$\forall\varepsilon_0>0,\exists\delta_b>0,\forall x,y\in [b,c):|x-y|<\delta_b\implies|g(x)-g(y)|<\varepsilon_0\tag{3}$$

Cause $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ if we took $\delta_{\omega}=\min\{\delta_0,\delta_a,\delta_b\}$ then we can finally write

> $$\forall\varepsilon_0>0,\exists\delta_{\omega}>0,\forall x,y\in (a,c):|x-y|<\delta_{\omega}\implies|g(x)-g(y)|<\varepsilon_0$$

Two questions:

1. Is my proof right? I think is right but Im not completely sure.
2. Can you tell me some different $\delta{-}\varepsilon$ proof for the same problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks ok except the abusive (and not correct) utilisation of quantifier.

Comment: Can you explain more in detail @Surb? What quantifier?

Comment: First you have that $\forall \varepsilon_1...$ $\forall \varepsilon_2...$, and then $\varepsilon_0=\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_2$. Since $\varepsilon_1$ and $\varepsilon_2$ are not defined, $\varepsilon_0$ is not defined. Same with $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$... I give you a correct proof in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. By uniform continuity on $(a,b]$ and $[b,c)$, there is $\delta_1>0$ s.t. $$\forall x,y\in (a,b],\  |x-y|<\delta_1\implies |g(x)-g(y)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$
and there is $\delta_2>0$ s.t. $$\forall x,y\in [b,c),\  |x-y|<\delta_2\implies |g(x)-g(y)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$
Let $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$ and $x\leq b\leq y$ s.t. $|x-y|\leq \delta$. Then,
$$|g(x)-g(y)|\leq |g(x)-g(b)|+|g(y)-g(b)|\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon.$$

As you see, $\varepsilon$ is fixed at the beginning. Since it's unspecified, we have the result for all $\varepsilon>0$, and this prove the claim.

Comment: Ah! I see. When I was thinking about some $\delta$ I was thinking about (I dont know why) a *unique* (or maximum) $\delta$ for each value of $\varepsilon$ so I tried to homogenize values. I see now that existence dont need any homogeinity. Thank you very much.